# Ant Build Tool Window in Intellij IDEA with setWLSEnv

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, ant, weblogic12c

One of our applications uses a number of Apache Ant tasks from Weblogic including (jwsc, clientgen, wldeploy) in building and deploying our application.  Normally when we build our application we first call setWLSEnv.cmd which sets up the environment by populating the PATH and CLASSPATH, which works from a cmd prompt (in Windows) and loads the classes necessary to run the 3 Weblogic tasks above.  However, the **Ant Build** Tool Window in Intellij IDEA doesn't seem to have a section to call setWLSEnv.

What is the best way to go about setting up **Ant Build** Tool Window with Weblogic (please note we are on Weblogic 12C).

Please Note: Although we are moving the application to Gradle, Intellij IDEA's **Gradle** Tool Window also doesn't seem to have a section in which you can call setWLSEnv.

So far I've tried the following with no success:

- executing setWLSEnv.bat (as suggested by CrazyCoder) from the task that calls the jwsc task using Ant's  task and this doesn't work as it appears that the environment variables set by setWLSEnv.cmd don't get inherited by the Ant build, since echoing doesn't print different values.
- creating a batch that calls setWLSEnv.cmd followed by the Intellij IDEA application, and while the application setWLSEnv.bat gets called, and it appears that the CLASSPATH and Path are set when I open a terminal in Intellij IDEA, when I run a task the Ant Build tool window, it fails with the same error as above.
- found the jwsc task (one of the 3 mentioned) in weblogic.jar, but when I modify the  with the jar's path it fails with a missing class. When I add that missing class, another missing class comes up, and this continues.

Comment: Answered in [the forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000153424-Ant-Build-Tool-Window-set-Weblogic-Environment-with-setWLSEnv).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried the suggestion mentioned in the post, but unfortunately it didn't work, as it appears that the environment variables set by setWLSEnv.cmd don't get inherited by the Ant build, since echoing doesn't print different values.

Comment: I'm afraid, there is no way to do it via any IntelliJ IDEA setting.